# Can we walk away from Lease if one of the member is still staying

Tags: rent, real-estate-leasing

My fiances dad died so we moved in with his mom to support her.
His Mom lived in the apartment for a couple years before we moved in.

Currently we are not getting along well financially. His Mom is being mean and spending all her money, we are stuck with having to buy everything for her apart from paying for rent etc.

We are tired of his Mom treating us like crap and like to move out of the apartment.

The apartment is on a year lease so if we leave lets say 5 months before the lease expiry; we may have to pay all the 5 months.

The question is if since his Mom continues to stay in the apartment and we move out, will the landlord allow us to move out [and collect his rent from his Mom] or request us to pay the rent for remaining period.

Comment: If you are on the lease, meaning named, then you are bound by it regardless of the internal situations. The "landlord" can make a judgement call but strictly from the lease perspective, you'd be on the hook unless there is language that would go in your favor.

Comment: How is she having you buy everything for her? She can't force you to spend your money on things for her. Maybe you just need to learn to say "No"?

Answer (score 2):

Initially intended as a long comment, but:

In this case we cannot tell you what to do, just provide minimal guidance.

If you're the primary lessee, you're on the hook for everything involving that unit.

If the mom decides not to pay rent, you're on the hook.
If the mom decides not to pay utilities and the contract requires running water and power during occupation, you're on the hook. If she brings in a pet or damages the unit, you're on the hook. If anything comes up during inspection on move-out, you're on the hook. And if they evict her, you got it, they really evicted you, and that goes on your record.

If you're co-lessee with the mom, you're *still* on the hook but so is she. In this case the relationship you want to maintain with the mom will influence your decisions, and the potential for power plays exists.

A strategy here would be to look at your lease, look at severance. Common terms are you either (a) find a tenant for the unit to sub-lease, (b) pay 2-3mo rent, potentially forfeit your deposit and sever the lease, or (c) pay the remainder of the value of the lease and sever the lease. Of course in "a" you could talk to the mother about sub-leasing (which the landlord **must** generally agree to in writing), but in "b" or "c" she would have to move elsewhere or become the tenant, meaning she pays a new deposit and first/last month's rent or what have you.

Without more information about your lease contract, and providing that IANAL, this is some very obvious guidance and I can do no more for you.